# Flurry reports cxx_destruct related crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, flurry, dealloc

I have a problem with an app crashing a few a times per day for a few users, I have no idea whats causing it and all I got is this stacktrace from flurry:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3b3ed626 _objc_msgSend + 5
1   TheApp                              0x000a3c57 -[MyViewController .cxx_destruct] + 327879 (MyViewController.m:11)
2   TheApp                              0x000aa4eb -[MyViewController .cxx_destruct] + 354651 (MyViewController.m:11)
3   TheApp                              0x000aa4eb -[MyViewController .cxx_destruct] + 354651 (MyViewController.m:11)
4   TheApp                              0x000a3c57 -[MyViewController .cxx_destruct] + 327879 (MyViewController.m:11)
5   TheApp                              0x000aa4eb -[MyViewController .cxx_destruct] + 354651 (MyViewController.m:11)
6   TheApp                              0x000aa4eb -[MyViewController .cxx_destruct] + 354651 (MyViewController.m:11)
7   TheApp                              0x000aa3b5 -[MyViewController .cxx_destruct] + 354341 (MyViewController.m:11)
8   TheApp                              0x000c462d -[MyViewController .cxx_destruct] + 461469 (MyViewController.m:11)
9   TheApp                              0x000c39f7 -[MyViewController .cxx_destruct] + 458343 (MyViewController.m:11)
10  TheApp                              0x000c5277 -[MyViewController .cxx_destruct] + 464615 (MyViewController.m:11)
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b8cb833 <redacted> + 10
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b8de921 <redacted> + 224
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b8deb21 <redacted> + 56
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3ba0dbd3 __pthread_wqthread + 298
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3ba0da98 _start_wqthread + 8
```

It looks like it's .cxx_destruct method is called multiple times and later somone tries to send a message to it? Why might the ViewControllers .cxx_destruct be called several times?

The class is contained within a UINavigationController which resides within a tabbar.

The ViewController's dealloc looks like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
    self.tableView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Arc is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same Error like `[SuperClassXY .cxx_destruct]`, but my code looks fine.

Then I found a few Breakpoints stacked directly on the `@implementation` line. (No idea where they come from)

Remove the Breakpoints and everything is fine.

Comment: Essentially it's not a crash, it just Breakpoints somewhere and you can click continue in the Debug Area.